# If statement not moving to else: when false?

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I am looping through 2 sets of rasters to do a extract by mask of one raster using the other, with ArcPy.

However, if the mask raster does not exist I want to skip to the next set of rasters.

Both sets of rasters are named the same.

```
for inras in inras_list[5:]:
    rasx=arcpy.sa.Raster(inras)
    base=(os.path.basename(inras).split(".")[0])
    print base
    trial=os.path.join(base+"_wilderness_reclass.tif") #name of second set of rasters
    print trial
    rasy=arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(workspace2, trial))
    print (os.path.join(workspace2, trial))
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(workspace2, trial)):
            inras_extent = rasx.extent
            print inras_extent
            maskras_extent = rasy.extent
            print maskras_extent
            arcpy.env.extent = rasy
            out_extract = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(rasx, rasy)
            outname = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.splitext(inras)[0] + "_opporwithoutroad_withoutwilderness.tif")
            arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(out_extract)
            out_extract.save(outname)
    else:
            print "Wilderness raster does not exist for the state. Saving original ras x as is"
            out_same= rasx
            outname = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.splitext(inras)[0] + "_opporwithoutroad_withoutwilderness.tif")
            arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(out_same)
            out_same.save(outname)
```

But the loop stops at the 9th file (because yes one set of rasters does not exists) and does not move to the next set of rasters i.e. 10th file.

The error I get-

```
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset E:\Staging\GLCarbonScience\Reforestation_Attribution\Outputs\Anciliary_variables\PAD_US_Outputs\Wildnerness\Wilderness_raster_reclass\09_wilderness_reclass.tif does not exist or is not supported
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Does any portion of the `else` occur e.g. does the print statement print?

Comment: What is in `inras_list`? How did you define it? Does it print the message in the `else` statement? Do you receive any error?

Comment: Nothing. And I don't understand why the if() is not being skipped to the else() section.

Comment: @umbe1987- inras_list is just a list of rasters defined as arcpy.ListRasters() to list all the rasters in the folder. I don't get the print statement in the else() section. I get the error that files does not exist, I guess after the if() section, but that is all.

Comment: If you're not receiving any error and the message in the else block does not print, to me sounds like the loop has finished. Again, what is inside `inras_list`? Try debugging your code before the if statement to make sure each loop the condition is doing what you want.

Comment: You might be getting the error ABOVE the print statement in line 7, where you call `arcpy.sa.Raster` on a non-existent file.

Comment: Please, include the error you are receiving in the question by editing it. Does the file mentioned in the error actually exist?

Comment: I know that inras_list is correct because the code runs for 8 sets of rasters before it stops @umbe1987

Comment: So, does `E:\Staging\GLCarbonScience\Reforestation_Attribution\Outputs\Anciliary_variables\PAD_US_Outputs\Wildnerness\Wilderness_raster_reclass\09_wilderness_reclass.tif` exist? And, do you maybe have also a line where this error occurs in your code?

Comment: @umbe1987 no it doesnt. hence it needs to be skipped and save only the rasx raster as is all coded in the else() section.

Comment: To me sounds the problem is more in the line `rasy=arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(workspace2, trial))` like @smiller said then ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving line 7

```
rasy=arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(workspace2, trial))
```

into the if statement.

It looks like this is being called on a non-existent .tif and will fail, causing the script to error out before reaching the if statement for this particular dataset.

```
for inras in inras_list[5:]:
    rasx=arcpy.sa.Raster(inras)
    base=(os.path.basename(inras).split(".")[0])
    print base
    trial=os.path.join(base+"_wilderness_reclass.tif") #name of second set of rasters
    print trial

    print (os.path.join(workspace2, trial))
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(workspace2, trial)):
            rasy=arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(workspace2, trial))
            inras_extent = rasx.extent
            print inras_extent
            maskras_extent = rasy.extent
            print maskras_extent
            arcpy.env.extent = rasy
            out_extract = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(rasx, rasy)
            outname = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.splitext(inras)[0] + "_opporwithoutroad_withoutwilderness.tif")
            arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(out_extract)
            out_extract.save(outname)
    else:
            print "Wilderness raster does not exist for the state. Saving original ras x as is"
            out_same= rasx
            outname = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.splitext(inras)[0] + "_opporwithoutroad_withoutwilderness.tif")
            arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(out_same)
            out_same.save(outname)
```

It's also possible that the name of the tif is causing some problems -- see Raster Naming Conventions. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/performing-analysis/output-raster-formats-and-names.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use try/except to continue to the next set when error occured.

```
for inras in inras_list[5:]:

    try:
        <your code>
    except:
        print ('error')
```